# conver json map to list in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to coding and I have a Json file, locally stored. I have accessed the file but when I store the Json data in a list, it throws a binding error.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Future<void> readJson() async {
    final response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/units.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);

    setState(() {
      List jsonList = data["length"];
      print(jsonList);
    });
  }
```

here this is how the json data look like.

```
{
    "length" : [

        {

            "name": "Meter",

            "conversion": 1.0,

            "base_unit": true

        },

        {

            "name": "Millimeter",

            "conversion": 1000.0

        },

        {

            "name": "Centimeter",

            "conversion": 100.0

        }
]
}
```

I have tried many things but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: please could you share the error

Comment: what error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your `data` to `List`, like this:

```
List jsonList = data["length"] as List;
```

Comment: it works, thanks but when I try to use it in a dropdown button. it throws a item == null error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine what is the data type of the list
for example if you want your list to be list of double to be able to hold distances you can try this code

```
jsonList = (data["length"] as List).map((e)=>e["conversion"]).toList();
```